# Unexplained high CPU usage of Celery worker and beat when started with Nginx and Gunicorn

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean, gevent

I have two applications in Digital Ocean with the following commands at startup:

**app1**

```
sh run.sh  # It starts celery worker, beat, nginx, gunicorn
```

**app2**

```
sh run-worker.sh # It starts celery worker, beat
```

My problem is that the processes of Celery worker and Celery beat of App1 consume almost 100% of the CPU after the image has been deployed on 1vCPU, 4 cores. Then the consumption slowly decrease and after 3 to 5 minutes, I assume when it has reached a reasonnable level, the worker finally get online.

Logs of both workers with 5 minutes delay:

[image]

High CPU usage right after image deployment:

[image]

My question is do I have to run the worker in a third App ? or is it a  configuration problem that could be fixed ?

This is how I start all the processes one after another:

**app1
sh run.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset

python3 manage.py migrate --settings project.env.prod
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.env.prod

celery -A project purge -f

echo "Start celery worker 1"
celery -A project worker --loglevel=INFO -P gevent --concurrency 24 -Q project_queue_1 -n worker1@project --detach

echo "Start celery beat"
celery -A project beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler --detach

echo "Start nginx"
service nginx start

echo "Start gunicorn"
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 0 -w 2 project.wsgi
```

**app2
sh run-worker.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.env.prod

echo 'Start celery worker 2'
celery -A project worker --loglevel=INFO -P gevent --concurrency 24 -Q project_queue_2 -n worker2@project
```

**celery.py**

```
@celeryd_after_setup.connect
def setup_direct_queue(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    logger.info("setup_direct_queue", worker=sender)


@celeryd_init.connect(sender=None)
def configure_worker(conf=None, **kwargs):
    logger.info("celeryd_init")


@worker_process_init.connect(sender=None)
def worker_process_init(sender=None, **kwargs):
    logger.info("worker_process_init", worker=sender)


@worker_init.connect(sender=None)
def worker_init(sender=None, **kwargs):
    logger.info("worker_init", worker=sender)


@worker_ready.connect(sender=None)
def worker_ready(sender=None, **kwargs):
    logger.info("worker_ready", worker=sender)
```

Comment: where is the time spent? just add an echo `date` statement between commands to see where the time is spent. Are the 2 scripts running on a single droplet? or 2 different ones? if it's on the same droplet, it's not surprising as you scripts are not concurrent. if it's 2 different droplets, then it has to do with how DO starts your droplets, which seems to be sequential here.

Comment: The code run on the App Plateform of DigitalOcean, within 2 different App. I deployed the image on the second App no more than 10 sec later that the first App. I can also say that the processes of both workers start right after the deployment -checked with `ps -ef` so an `echo` would return more or less the same time.

Comment: what about the queue used by celery? doesn't that need to be staged too, which may explain the delay in getting initialized?

Comment: Each worker listen to its own queue, and the two queues are defined in `celery.py`. What information should I get ? Also I just notice that `ps -aux` show that `celery -A project worker` and `celery -A project beat` use 94% of CPU and 94% of memory, while it's not active yet. Very strange. The CPU and RAM consumption slowly decrease, few seconds later it's 58% and 57%

Comment: According to the screenshot, celery is using 50MB, and gunicorn is using 200 MB of memory. That is really not a lot for a Python application.

Comment: True, it's not 100% of RAM as I stated initially but 100% of CPU. What I don't understand is that the worker isn't processing tasks after the image has been deployed, so it shouln't consume that much. Seems like a cohabitation problem with Gunicorn.